# ICE default IO error handler doing an exit(), pid = 11281, errno = 4

Tags: c, linux, unix, centos6, pyqt5

One of our PyQt app throwa an error about ICEAuthority as below and exit -

> ICE default IO error handler doing an exit(), pid = 11281, errno = 4

On looking at the trace, we see the following -

```
write(25, "\1\0\3\200\3\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\377rtStyle", 32) = 32
read(25, 0x16a67f0, 8) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
— SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) —
write(6, "\0", 1) = 1
rt_sigreturn(0x2) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
write(2, "ICE default IO error handler doi"..., 69) = 69
```

This looks like the ICEAuthority file read operation failed to restart after handling the SIGCHLD for one of the processes we spawned from the PyQt app. On googling, there are a lot of reports about ICEAuthority file failure and people suggest restarting the system, deleting the .ICEAuthority file, or unsetting SESSION_MANAGER. We are inclined to unset SESSION_MANAGER in our PyQt app for now. But I'd like to understand why the operation failed to restart the read operation of the ICEAuthority file. Is this a bug in the gnome-session code? Is anyone aware of it?

Also I'd like to mention that I tried setting SA_RESTART to false for the SIGCHLD handle to restart the operation. This failed to work.

Please find below our system details -

> Linux nyc-nx-l01.schrodinger.com 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 16 18:37:12 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

Comment: "SA_RESTART to false for SIGCHLD handle to restart the operation" You have to set that flag, not clear it, in order to have syscalls be automatically restarted. It could be code elsewhere that overrides your own signal handler. It does seem some code somewhere does not handle EINTR properly, the question is which code.

Answer (score 36):

I had the same error message when starting 'keepassx' on Ubuntu. Deleting my ~/.ICEauthority file fixed it. Only deleted it once, have never had the problem since.

Comment: is there any potential danger in deleting `~/.ICEauthority`?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't know what it does. I have not noticed any ill-effects.

Answer (score 0):

In my linux machine USB was not readable, and then kile was also showing the error 
"ICE default IO error handler doing an exit(), pid = 11212, errno = 0".

Deleting the file .ICEauthority, worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I do not think there is a problem deleting the .ICEauthority file.  That folder holds torrent cookies probably from a private tracker or something.  I still believe ktorrent is one of the best torrent clients because it gives a timeout time to stagnate torrents and tries to load up active ones.  In other words, the client always tries to make sure it is working with active torrent sources.