# ICE default IO error handler doing an exit(), pid = ..., errno = 32 when running some python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I am running python 3.4.3 on xubuntu 14.04.

I have a smallish python program (my modules have about 1000 lines but I import some standard data stuff like numpy, pandas, sci-kit learn) that is run from the command line that analyzes some data and generates some output files.

It was running without issue.  After making some changes, the program runs and generates the output files as expected, but now when it terminates, the line

```
ICE default IO error handler doing an exit(), pid = ..., errno = 32
```

is written to the terminal.

I searched a bit on the internet and came up with two other SO questions [Q: ICE Default IO error in Spyder Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897422/ice-default-io-error-in-spyder-ubuntu?s=1%7C3.4139) and [Q: ICE default IO error handler doing an exit(), pid = 11281, errno = 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621070/ice-default-io-error-handler-doing-an-exit-pid-11281-errno-4?s=2%7C3.2448).  They both seem to suggest moving or deleting my

```
$HOME/.ICEauthority
```

file.

I also came up with [Could not update ICEauthority file /home/user/.ICEauthority](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1841457), [What is the role of the .ICEauthority file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439455/what-is-the-role-of-the-iceauthority-file), and [Inter-Client Exchange (ICE) Protocol](http://www.xfree86.org/4.5.0/ice.pdf).  I was excited about finding the Protocol because I hoped I could find my errno 32 and shed some light on my predicament.  Unfortunately, I could not parse the Protocol well enough to find any information on my error.

Any ideas on how to fix this error that don't involve deleting or moving the .ICEauthority file?  Barring that, any ideas on what might be causing this error?  Barring that, any ideas on where I could go look for more information?

Sorry, that I don't have a minimal working example.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20621070/2623899

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem, when run some python script, which use matplotlib (OS Debian). To fix error I switched "matplotlib backend" in mode 'TkAgg' (because it's mode by default I just deleted row, which sets other mode):

```
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg'))
```

And it fixed error (without OS re-logging, I just restart python console).

Comment: 7 years later, this still happens. This is the solution. You need to do ```matplotlib.use('TkAgg'))``` and the error is gone. Removing "authority" files and rebooting didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I was in a similar situation (also XUbuntu 14.04, also trying to run some python code, particularly code that used pyplot), and I found that deleting `~/.Xauthority` in addition to `~/.ICEauthority` and then logging out and logging back in helped me.

I'm not sure why it worked, but if you're still having this problem it might be worth trying.

Additionally, I needed to install the latest version of `python-matplotlib` from apt-get instead of using the version I had installed using pip.

Comment: In Debian testing, I solved the same problem by uninstalling matplotlib module installed with pip, and install python3-matplotlib from repositories.